# Getting the name of python enum class

Tags: python, enums

Let's say that I have a class like this

```py
class ErrorCreatingObjectResult(enum.Enum):
    NONE = 0
    OBJECT_ALREADY_EXIST = 1
    UID_NOT_REGESTIRE = 2
    CREATOR_NOT_REGESTIRE = 3
```

and an object with an attribute from this class

```py
class CreatingObjectMessage:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.message = 'done creating object'
        self.error = False
        self.errorType = ErrorCreatingObjectResult.NONE
```

and I want to generate the dict object from this class by calling

```py
def convert2serialize(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        return {k: convert2serialize(v) for k, v in obj.items()}
    elif hasattr(obj, "_ast"):
        return convert2serialize(obj._ast())
    elif not isinstance(obj, str) and hasattr(obj, "__iter__"):
        return [convert2serialize(v) for v in obj]
    elif hasattr(obj, "__dict__"):
        return {
            k: convert2serialize(v)
            for k, v in obj.__dict__.items()
            if not callable(v) and not k.startswith('_')
        }
    else:
        return obj

r = CreatingObjectMessage()
convert2serialize(r)
```

this giving me an empty results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Editing the convert2serialize function fixed it

```py
def convert2serialize(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, enum.Enum):
        return {type(obj).mro()[0].__name__: obj.name}
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        return {k: convert2serialize(v) for k, v in obj.items()}
    elif hasattr(obj, "_ast"):
        return convert2serialize(obj._ast())
    elif not isinstance(obj, str) and hasattr(obj, "__iter__"):
        return [convert2serialize(v) for v in obj]
    elif hasattr(obj, "__dict__"):
        return {
            k: convert2serialize(v)
            for k, v in obj.__dict__.items()
            if not callable(v) and not k.startswith('_')
        }
    else:
        return obj
```

this is the part where I could get the name of the class

```py
type(obj).mro()[0].__name__
```

Comment: So what did you actually change, and is this bug fix something you expect anyone else to find useful? Just because you had a question and manage to fix it yourself doesn't mean it makes for a useful question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: It was good idea, someone may having the same pain when I was trying to do,

Comment: Someone having the same pain would have even more trying to pick out the actual answer from your function.  Keeping the whole function as an example is fine, but please pull out the actual answer to it's own snippet.  For example, the first part of your answer could read: "The name of the enum class can be found with: `obj.__class__.__name__`."

Comment: I don’t think so that you tried the code

Comment: I tried using your enum, and getting the name worked just like I said it would.  Please add that part of the problem to your original question, along with `print()`s of the object so we can see what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Getting the name of an enum member's class is as easy as:

```
member.__class__.__name__
```

Comment: This is where I had an error with the enum, the class property was returning none

Comment: @NimrSawafta: Please add that to your question, including `print()`s of the object showing the error.